# How to make output like this using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what i need to make as output ? How can i do it using bootstrap ?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzmWN.png)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
   -- Content here--
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   -- content--
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

how to add specific gap between these two columns please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a gap between the two columns, why don't you simply add another column? Something like this.Reduce one or two of the other columns by an appropriate measure.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7" style="background-color:white">
   -- Content here--
  </div>  
<div class="col-lg-1"  style="background-color:grey">
   -- content--
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4"  style="background-color:white">
   -- content--
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also add a gutter class and give it appropriate styling. Google it if you want, but this is relatively easier.

Comment: is there any problem with responsiveness of the site? while adding an extra gray colored colomn ?!

Comment: There shouldn't be considering that Bootstrap will take care of it!

Comment: Check this[link](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13977/)

Comment: No its perfectly working one thank you :) @satejS

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin to the left side of 2nd grid.

```
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    Content here
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 2%;">
   -- content--
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `offset` to the 2nd `div` as below and make it `col-lg-3`

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
   -- Content here--
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
   -- content--
  </div>
</div>
```